# Firewall with application rules for iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, jailbreak, firewall

I've read some other topics about *not needed* firewall for iPad's, but I'm searching the other way of security or (more important) to help my budget.
I need firewall that has incoming/outcoming rules for every app. Rules should be remembered and asked only once, but easily to change. Good would be having profiles which I could switch when needed.

Is something like this available for iPad? Is it working without Jailbreak?

P.S. It should block apple services too when I want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Firewall iP

[Firewall iP](http://yllier.webs.com/firewall.html) lets you [block connections](http://yllier.webs.com/usage.html) from apps on your jailbroken iOS device. You can set up custom rules to block/allow certain TCP & UDP connections.

[image]
[image]
[image]

---

### iOS 7

In response to your comment about 3G data, in iOS 7 you can specifically set certain apps/services through your 3G data connection:

[image]

Comment: is it good as they are writing about? made by trustworthy developers?

Comment: I have used Firewall iP in the past, and it works great, especially with the new update for iOS 6 with the new interface design (that was one of the things I didn't like about the old Firewall iP). tl;dr Yeah it's great :)

Comment: oh, great! So I have to check how to Jailbreak my iPad and test it. Thank you very much!

Comment: apropos iOS7 - it is for 3g mainly, but I want to block some apps from wifi too. Privacy maniac ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is no such app on an non-jailbroken iPad.  Apple doesn't allow the low level access to the system would be needed to implement such a thing.

If you are concerned about running up data charges your best option is probably to turn cellular data on or off as needed.  From a security perspective you try an external firewall when connected to a network you control.

Comment: iPad is for me an device on the go only, so I'm connecting to spots around the world. when I turn 3G on updates are checked and so on that makes costs.
for Jailbroken iPad can I find something what I'm asking about?

Comment: There are firewalls available for jail broken iOS devices.

Comment: what are names of them? I can't find any with rules. can you give me some concrete examples?

Comment: I've never used it, but Firewall iP is the one that comes up in my searches.